# Canvas resize

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь осилить ресайз изображения через canvas.

Сама функция вопросов не вызывает:

```
function fileResize(image){
    var canvas      = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx         = canvas.getContext("2d");      
    var newImage    = new Image();
    newImage.onload     = function(){

        canvas.width    = 300;
        canvas.height   = 300;

        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 300, 300);
                // В этом месте измененное изображение показывается.
                //document.getElementById("testIMG").src =   canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    }
    newImage.src    =   image.result; }
```

Но не могу понять, как потом получить само это изображение, вне функции. Т.е. чтобы получилось что-то типа этого:

```
resizedImage    =   fileResize(image);
document.getElementById("testIMG").src  =   resizedImage.src;
```

Максимально успешный мой результат - это просто черный прямоугольник...
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А тут вам надо `callback` использовать, т.к. метод `onload` работает асинхронно!

```
function fileResize(image, callback){
    var canvas      = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx         = canvas.getContext("2d");      
    var newImage    = new Image();
    newImage.onload     = function(){

        canvas.width    = 300;
        canvas.height   = 300;

        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 300, 300);

        /**
         * вызываем нашу функцию после обработки
         */
        callback(canvas);
    }
    newImage.src = image;
}

fileResize("/logo.png", function(canvas) {
    document.getElementById("testIMG").src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
});
```